# In bash, download and install a package but only if not installed

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a script that can run on CentOS or Ubuntu, but my logic might not be optimal. This part is just doing an install for CentOS

```
type apt &> /dev/null && MANAGER=dnf && DISTRO="Debian/Ubuntu"
type yum &> /dev/null && MANAGER=yum && DISTRO="RHEL/Fedora/CentOS"
type dnf &> /dev/null && MANAGER=dnf && DISTRO="RHEL/Fedora/CentOS"   # $MANAGER=dnf will be default if both dnf and yum are present

[[ "$MANAGER" = "dnf" ]] && (NOT) [ type pydf &> /dev/null ] && wget -P /tmp/ https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm
[[ "$MANAGER" = "dnf" ]] && [[ -f /tmp/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm ]] &> /dev/null && rpm -i /tmp/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm && rm /tmp/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm
```

I want to check `[ is dnf is present? AND is dfc NOT present? ]`. If these are true THEN download the rpm, then `[ is dnf present? AND is the rpm present ]`. If these are true, then install the rpm.

In each case, I'm a little confused if I am using the right approach, and I never really know if I should be using `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`. I get that `&&` is 'only if previous statement is true, then run the next one', but I feel a bit confused that I'm maybe not approaching this is an correct / optimal way (and definitely, my logic is broken in the download line I think)?

Should it maybe look more like this, though I don't know how to construct the first condition:

```
if [[ $MANAGER == "dnf" && ( NOT type pydf &> /dev/null ) ]]; then 
    wget -P /tmp/ https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm
    RPM=/tmp/pydf-12-11.fc35.noarch.rpm; type $RPM &> /dev/null && rpm -i $RPM && rm $RPM
fi
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to check if `pydf` is installed. `dnf` and `yum` should already be able to determine by itself whether the appropriate package is installed, and if not to download the package itself.

Comment: But many packages are not in CentOS. so it says the package is not there, hence why I want this logic to work as a general exercise in how to handle when the package manager cannot find the package.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for `pydf` or download the package itself; that's the job of `dnf` or `yum`.

```
if type dnf; then
    dnf install pydf
elif type yum; then
    yum install pydf
elif type apt; then
    apt get pydf
else
    echo "What package manager do you use?" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: But many packages are not in CentOS. so it says the package is not there, hence why I want this logic to work as a general exercise in how to handle when the package manager cannot find the package. What you've said here is what I would do if the package was available in the repo (but it is not).

Comment: Then specify a repo that *does* have the package.

Comment: I can't, it doesn't exist (I think!)

Comment: You can host your own repository. Download the file once, put it in your local repository, then use that.

Comment: You have a system for doing that in a couple of lines? So the goal is a script that I run on CentOS or Ubuntu systems and it installs some settings and packages. Hosting a repository seems quite a lot of overkill. 1. the package is not available in the repo (so `dnf install pydf` does not work. 2. I would like to have logic to wget the file as required in a sensible way. That's it really. I would love to see how you build a local repository out of curiosity, but it is somewhat overkill for this maybe.

Comment: It's not overkill at all. If you have enough machines that you need a script that handles updates for you, you almost certainly do not want to rely on the availability of an outside resource to provide the necessary package, nor do you want to download the package from the external resource every time you do a local installation. Download the package *once*, when necessary, to your local repository, then install from there. (Note this implies that having a local mirror of the remote repository is also desirable.)

Comment: I get a new laptop from work, I want to configure it as I want it, plus some little local linux boxes that I sometimes blow away and rebuild, so it's definitely massive overkill. A local mirror of the remote repository is also kind of overkill. I was just looking for some simple logic as is asked in the question.